# how to improve performance: loop for each level of a factor (in R)

Tags: r, performance, loops

I found it very slow to loop for each level of a factor.

The data is the schedule of some trains:

```
 col1      col2       col3     col4            col5
 train    start     density    starttime     arrivaltime
[factor] [factor]  [factor]   [date&time]   [date&time]
```

There are 10m rows. There are ~1k trains, so each train has ~10k row.

I tried the following test code:

```
data = data[order(data$train, data$starttime), ]   # sort according to train, and then according to starttime
length1  = numeric( length(levels(data$train))  )
ii = 1
sub = data[1,]   # initialize it           
for (t in levels(data$train))
{
  sub =  subset(data, train==t)  #subset of each train
  length1[ii] = nrow(sub)
  ii = ii +1 
  print(ii)
}
```

It works very slowly - couple seconds for each loop on my laptop. I wonder if there's something I can do to improve the efficiency.

E.g., `sub` is a variable that changes in every loop. Should I avoid copying those rows into `sub`? `sub` changes length while looping, should I give it bigger memory space when initializing?

ps
What I really want to do is, for each train, if the destiny city == the start city of the next trip. The code is:

```
data = data[order(data$train, data$starttime), ]   # sort according to train, and then according to starttime
sub = data[1,]   # initialization           
for (t in levels(data$train))
{
  sub =  subset(data, train==t)   #subset of each train

  for (i in 1:(nrow(sub)-1)   )
  {
    if ( as.character(sub$destiny[i]) != as.character(sub$start[i+1]) )
    # if the destiny != the start city of the next trip
    { do something   }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the first part of your question, a simple `table(data$train)` will suffice to know how many rows each train level has.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using `dplyr` package. It was written exactly for this purpose by Hadley and is very intuitive to use. The following links have tutorials on that package.

http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/11068_8bc42d6df61341b2bed45e9a9a3bf9f4.html

http://www.r-bloggers.com/hands-on-dplyr-tutorial-for-faster-data-manipulation-in-r/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWjqLW-u3hc

Comment: Thank you @koundy! I tried it - it's faster！ （though not 1000X faster as mentioned in the manual of data.table - some people said data.table and dplyr are comparable in performance)